# Async.AwaitEvent does not cancel after invocation of underlying event

Tags: .net, events, asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to understand [Async.AwaitEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370253.aspx) behavior. According to documentation:

> Creates an asynchronous computation that waits for a single invocation of a CLI event by adding a handler to the event. Once the computation completes or is cancelled, the handler is removed from the event.

and from the remarks section:

> The computation will respond to cancellation while waiting for the event. If a cancellation occurs, and cancelAction is specified, then it is executed, and the computation continues to wait for the event. If cancelAction is not specified, then cancellation causes the computation to cancel immediately.

I do not specify any kind of cancel action and therefore I expect that event will be processed once and as soon as this happened, handler should be unsubscribed. But if I run this sample, I can see that event handled over and over again.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control

let timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000.0)
timer.AutoReset <- true
timer.Start()

let fn = async {
    let timerEvent = Async.AwaitEvent timer.Elapsed

    for _ in [1..10] do
        let! x = timerEvent
        printfn "elapsed event occurred at %O" x.SignalTime
}

fn |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Output:

```
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:21
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:23
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:25
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:27
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:29
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:31
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:33
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:35
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:37
elapsed event occurred at 19.06.2014 23:46:39
```

Is this behavior differ from documented one? If not, then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timerEvent` is of type `Async<ElapsedEventArgs>`. In general, an `Async<'something>` is just a representation of an async computation that you could run in future, possibly repeatedly. A construct like `let!` is how an `Async<'something>` is actually run.

This is similar to how `let f() = printfn "wibble"` just defines a function `f` that will print "wibble" each time it is run.

So what's happening here is that each time `let! x = timerEvent` runs, you're subscribing to the event again and waiting for it to happen.

Once the event occurs, that particular subscription is cancelled, but control continues past the `let!` to the `printfn`, and then around the loop again and a new subscription is made.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. I was also trying to get `cancelAction` called, but without any success. I re-defined `timerEvent` as follows `let timerEvent = Async.AwaitEvent(timer.Elapsed, fun () -> printfn "cancelled")` and `"cancelled"` was never printed. Could you please advice?

Comment: How are you cancelling the async? I think this probably needs a fresh question, though.